# Error upon spawning multiple boundingBoxes "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to create `boundingBoxes` (Collision) between an enemy and the bullets that it's struck with. Unfortunately, I'm being presented with the error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` every time a enemy leaves the screen, or more than 1 bullet is spawned at a time.

Both bounding boxes are created in the `Update` functions of the bullet & enemy classes as such:

```
boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
```

This is the relevant code being used in my `Game1` update function:

```
for (int i = bullets.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    bullets[i].Update(gameTime);

ERROR OCCURS HERE ->     if (bullets[i].boundingBox.Intersects(enemies[i].boundingBox))
                            {
                                score += 1;
                                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                            }

                    //Bullets being destroyed upon leaving 
                    if (bullets[i].position.Y < 0)
                        bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, Here is how I implemented the bullet list into the `Game1` class if that helps at all?:

```
List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();

    public void Shoot (Vector2 pos, Vector2 dir, float speed)
    {
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet(bulletTexture);

        bullet.position     = pos;
        bullet.direction    = dir;
        bullet.speed        = speed;

        if (bullets.Count() < 40)       //Maximum amount of bullets
            bullets.Add(bullet);
    }
```

Comment: And where exactly does this exception occur?

Comment: My apologies, the error occurs on the 5th line in the 2nd block of code: - "if (bullets[i].boundingBox.Intersects(enemies[i].boundingBox))"

Comment: That's what I thought, does this line when translating into written language make any sense? You are checking whether the i-th bullet hits the i-th enemy. Can't it hit another one?

Comment: As it currently stands, no. But I would like it to. I'm not sure how I should go about fixing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to guess, the error comes from the `if (bullets[i].boundingBox.Intersects(enemies[i].boundingBox))` statement.

Basically, do you have the same amount of enemies and bullets all the time? If not, then it will fail whenever the numbers are different.

Why is this? Well, you are using two different collections, `bullets` and `enemies`, and taking the element at position `i`.

So if you have 5 bullets but only 1 enemy in the collection, the first iteration of the for will have `i = 4`, a position that does not exist in the `enemies` collection (it only has the `enemies[0]` position).

One way to solve the problem would be:

```
foreach (enemy in enemies)
    foreach (bullet in bullets)
        if (bullet.boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.boundingBox)) 
        { 
            // do your logic here.
        }
```

You go through every enemy, and for each one you check if any bullet is intersecting with it. This is not the best solution performance wise, but I think it's a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I do appreciate this!